# Sorting NSArray by NSOrderedSet

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsarray, nssortdescriptor, nsorderedset

I'm doing an `NSFetchRequest` with the following predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"index IN %@", indexes];
```

... where `indexes` is an `NSOrderedSet` of numbers.

This gives me an array of "randomly sorted" objects with given indexes. I need to sort this so that the objects appear in the same order as in the ordered set.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

**Update**

Here is a category based on Martin R's answer:

```
@implementation NSArray (SortUsingValues)

- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingValues:(NSOrderedSet *)values keyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
{
    NSAssert([values isKindOfClass:[NSOrderedSet class]], nil);
    NSAssert([keyPath isKindOfClass:[NSString class]], nil);
    return [self sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id object, id otherObject) {
        id value = [object valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
        id otherValue = [otherObject valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
        NSUInteger indexOfValue = [values indexOfObject:value];
        NSUInteger indexOfOtherValue = [values indexOfObject:otherValue];
        if (indexOfValue > indexOfOtherValue) return NSOrderedDescending;
        else if (indexOfValue < indexOfOtherValue) return NSOrderedAscending;
        else return NSOrderedSame;
    }];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way to use a sort descriptor in the fetch request for that purpose. But you can sort the result array after fetching according to the indexes:

```
NSArray *sorted = [results sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSUInteger idx1 = [indexes indexOfObject:[obj1 valueForKey:@"index"]];
    NSUInteger idx2 = [indexes indexOfObject:[obj2 valueForKey:@"index"]];
    return idx1 - idx2;
}];
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. BTW, I've just updated my question with a category based on your answer.