# Advantage to searching core data via multiple ids at once vs many back to back

Tags: ios, core-data

I am wondering if I build an NSDictionary with a certain key that has as a value an array of  managed IDs and wanted to pull up those objects when the key was used, is there a way to load all those objects or would I need to load one at a time?

Example:

NSDict:
"Apple" = NSArray[id1,id2,id3,etc...]

1. Somehow load all ids from core data at once (and what method is used for this)
2. Load each one one by one (for id in array... Etc)
   ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an array of managed object IDs then you can fetch all objects with a single fetch request:

```
NSArray *objectIDs = ...;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"YourEntityName"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", objectIDs];
NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

However, the order of the objects returned in the `result` array need not be the same as the order of the provided objects IDs. In other words, it is not guaranteed that `result[i]` is the object with the ID `objectIDs[i]`.

If necessary, you can sort the result array according to the object IDs, using the code from this answer: [Sorting NSArray by NSOrderedSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617795/sorting-nsarray-by-nsorderedset/15618277#15618277).